# Why is this Swift struct instantiation crashing?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift struct `Reflection` like this:

```
struct Reflection {
let title: String
let body: String
let author: String
let favorite: Bool
let creationDate: Date
let id: UUID
}

extension Reflection {
var plistRepresentation: [String: AnyObject] {
    return [
        "title": title as AnyObject,
        "body": body as AnyObject,
        "author": author as AnyObject,
        "favorite": favorite as AnyObject,
        "creationDate": creationDate as AnyObject,
        "id": id as AnyObject
    ]
}

init(plist: [String: AnyObject]) {
    title = plist["title"] as! String
    body = plist["body"] as! String
    author = plist["author"] as! String
    favorite = plist["favorite"] as! Bool
    creationDate = plist["creationDate"] as! Date
    id = plist["id"] as! UUID
}    
}

class StorageController {
fileprivate let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default
    .urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    .first!

fileprivate var notesFileURL: URL {
    return documentsDirectoryURL
        .appendingPathComponent("Notes")
        .appendingPathExtension("plist")
}

func save(_ notes: [Reflection]) {
    let notesPlist = notes.map { $0.plistRepresentation } as NSArray
    notesPlist.write(to: notesFileURL, atomically: true)
}

func fetchNotes() -> [Reflection] {
    guard let notePlists = NSArray(contentsOf: notesFileURL) as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
        return []
    }
    return notePlists.map(Reflection.init(plist:))
}
}

class StateController {
fileprivate let storageController: StorageController
fileprivate(set) var notes: [Reflection]

init(storageController: StorageController) {
    self.storageController = storageController
    self.notes = storageController.fetchNotes()
}

func add(_ note: Reflection) {
    notes.append(note)
    storageController.save(notes)
}

func update(_ note: Reflection) {
    for (index, storedNote) in notes.enumerated() {
        guard storedNote.id == note.id else {
            continue
        }
        notes[index] = note
        storageController.save(notes)
        break
    }
}
}
```

Instantiating a `Reflection` like this in `viewWillAppear` crashes my app:

```
import UIKit

class NotesViewController: UIViewController {
var stateController: StateController!

fileprivate var dataSource: FeedDataSource!

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let reflection = Reflection(title: "Hello", body: "world", author: "Alex", favorite: true, creationDate: Date(), id: UUID())
    //stateController.add(reflection)
    dataSource = FeedDataSource(notes: stateController.notes)
    tableView.dataSource = dataSource
    tableView.reloadData()
}

class FeedDataSource: NSObject {
var notes: [Reflection]!

init(notes: [Reflection]) {
    self.notes = notes
}
}

extension FeedDataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return notes.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reflectionCell", for: indexPath) as! ReflectionCell
    let index = indexPath.row
    let note = notes[index]
    cell.model = ReflectionCell.Model(data: note)
    return cell
}
}

The cell class:

class ReflectionCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak fileprivate var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak fileprivate var bodyLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak fileprivate var authorLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak fileprivate var bookmarkButton: UIButton!
fileprivate var id: UUID!

var model: Model? {
    didSet {
        guard let model = model else {
            return
        }
        titleLabel.text = model.title
        bodyLabel.text = model.body
        authorLabel.text = model.author
        bookmarkButton.isSelected = model.favorite
        id = model.id
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    bookmarkButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bookmark-Highlighted"), for: .selected)
}
}

extension ReflectionCell {
struct Model {
    let title: String
    let body: String
    let author: String
    let favorite: Bool
    let id: UUID

    init(data: Reflection) {
        title = data.title
        body = data.body
        author = data.author
        favorite = data.favorite
        id = data.id
    }
}
}
```

I get no console output, just a main thread SIGABRT error. What could be going on?

Comment: The code you posted works just fine in an Xcode 9.2 playground.

Comment: Hmm... any idea why I'm not getting any console output either?

Comment: Not related to your issue but you should use Swift native dictionary type `[String:Any]` since Swift 3. Note that you are forcing unwrap your dictionary values so if you fail to pass any value it will crash

Comment: You need to post code that actually crashes. The code you posted has no errors at all.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the suggestion. But that seems to be unrelated to the issue, as I'm not accessing the plist var nor using the plist initializer. I'm getting the issues with the default initializer

Comment: Sorry but as already mentioned by @rmaddy the code you posted won't crash your app. What'
s the error you are getting?

Comment: @rmaddy see edit for complete example

Comment: Which line exactly causes the crash?

Comment: @rmaddy I have no idea how to find what line. As I said there is no output in the console, just a SIGABRT in the AppDelegate

Comment: Set an All Exceptions breakpoint and it will break on the line that causes the exception.

Comment: @rmaddy it is the dequeReuseableCell line that fails. Something wrong with the cast?

Answer (score 0):

Like an idiot I was cleaning up my code and commented out the line registering the nib for the reuse identifier. However, I do think it would help if Xcode could print out a useful error message for such a mistake.